# Apply Condition in Cucumber Feature Scenario

Tags: selenium, cucumber

How would I handle the following kind of scenario using Cucumber Java with Selenium:

```
  Scenario: Raise Invoice by User according to Raise Invoice Type.
  When I select the Raise Invoice Type as "RaiseInvoiceType"
  IF RaiseInvoiceType == 'ABC'
     Method ABC()
  else if RaiseInvoiceType == 'XYZ'
     Method XYZ()
```

"RaiseInvoiceType" is a variable and is dependent on the radio button or drop-down.
How to implement cucumber feature files and step definition class methods with the condition?

Comment: show us the step definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Background**

Cucumber feature files are all about bridging the conversational gap between the business and the development team, and thus, code and conditional statements should never appear inside them.

**The Solution**

The solution to your problem is how you write the step definition.

Using Cucumber's Ruby implementation as an example:

```rb
When('I select the Raise Invoice Type as "$invoice_type"') do | invoice_type |
  if invoice_type == 'ABC'
     method_abc
  else 
     if invoice_type == 'XYZ'
        method_xyz
     else
        raise 'Unknown invoice type'
     end
  end
end
```

This brings the code and conditional statements out of the feature file, which is in essence meant to be living documentation of the *behaviours* of the application/system

**Further Improvements**

But I would go so far as to change the wording of the step too:

```
Scenario Outline: Raise Invoice by User according to Raise Invoice Type.
  When I raise the invoice type "<invoice_type>"
  Then some expected behaviour

Examples:
  | invoice_type |
  | ABC          |
  | XYZ          |
```

This brings the step away from implementation (that could be dropdown, radio or text boxes for example), and more towards behaviours of the system in place  - the feature that this scenario is highlighting is that you should be able to raise an invoice, not that you should have a list of options to choose from in a select box.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing here is the difference between the two invoice types. Each type is important to your business so I would create a step for each type e.g.

`When I raise an ABC invoice` and `When I raise an XYZ invoice`

When implementing the step definitions I might then think about using the same helper method to reduce the code e.g.

```
When I raise an ABC invoice' do
  raise_invoice type: 'abc'
end

When I raise an XYZ invoice' do
  raise_invoice type: 'xyz'
end
```

and then have a helper method deal with HOW you raise the invoice.

```
def raise_invoice(type: )
  click_radio('invoice', type)
end
```

This gives you very simple step definitions, no conditionals or other complications in your step defs and a simple method to deal with the interaction in the browser.

*note all code above is pseudo-code/ruby*